# Kd-Tree flawed K nearest neighbor

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

Disclaimer: There are some bad practices in this following code

Hello, I just had a few questions on how to correctly format my KD tree K nearest neighbor search. Here is an example of my function.

```
void nearest_neighbor(Node *T, int K) {
  if (T == NULL) return;
  nearest_neighbor(T->left, K); 
  //do stuff find dist etc
  if(?)nearest_neighbor(T->right, K);  
 }
```

This code is confusing so I will try to explain it. My function only takes the k value and a Node T. What I am trying to do is find the distance between the current node and every other value in the structure. These all work, the issue I'm having is understanding when and how to call the recursive calls nearest_neighbor(T->left/T->right,K) I know I am meant to prune the calls to the right side but I'm not sure how to do this. This is an multidimensional KD Tree by the way. Any guidance to better examples would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to implement like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search) says, where for your specific question, this:

> Starting with the root node, the algorithm moves down the tree
>   recursively, in the same way that it would if the search point were
>   being inserted (i.e. it goes left or right depending on whether the
>   point is lesser than or greater than the current node in the split
>   dimension).

answers the question. Of course you can have this image in mind:

[image]

where if you have more two dimensions like in the example, you simply split in the first dimension, then in the second, then in the third, then in the forth and so on, and then you follow a cyclic policy, so that when you reach the final dimension, you start from the first dimension again.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to keep a global point closest to the target, updating with newly discovered points and never descending into an n-gon that can't possibly contain a point closer than the nearest to the target already found. I'll show it in C rather than C++. You can easily translate to object-oriented form.

```
#define N_DIM <k for the k-D tree>

typedef float COORD; 

typedef struct point_s {
  COORD x[N_DIM];
} POINT;

typedef struct node_s {
  struct node_s *lft, *rgt;
  POINT p[1];
} NODE;

POINT target[1];    // target for nearest search
POINT nearest[1];   // nearest found so far
POINT b0[1], b1[1]; // search bounding box

bool prune_search() {
  // Return true if no point in the bounding box [b0..b1] is closer
  // to the target than than the current value of nearest.
}

void search(NODE *node, int dim);

void search_lft(NODE *node, int dim) {
  if (!node->lft) return;
  COORD save = b1->p->x[dim];
  b1->p->x[dim] = node->p->x[dim];
  if (!prune_search()) search(node->lft, (dim + 1) % N_DIM);
  b1->p->x[dim] = save; 
}

void search_rgt(NODE *node, int dim) {
  if (!node->rgt) return;
  COORD save = b0->p->x[dim];
  b0->p->x[dim] = node->p->x[dim];
  if (!prune_search()) search(node->rgt, (dim + 1) % N_DIM);
  b0->p->x[dim] = save; 
}

void search(NODE *node, int dim) {
  if (dist(node->p, target) < dist(nearest, target)) *nearest = *node->p;
  if (target->p->x[dim] < node->p->x[dim]) {
    search_lft(node, dim);
    search_rgt(node, dim);
  } else {
    search_rgt(node, dim);
    search_lft(node, dim);
  }
}

/** Set *nst to the point in the given kd-tree nearest to tgt. */
void get_nearest(POINT *nst, POINT *tgt, NODE *root) {     
  *b0 = POINT_AT_NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
  *b1 = POINT_AT_POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  *target = *tgt;
  *nearest = *root->p;
  search(root, 0);
  *nst = *nearest;
}
```

Note this is not *the* most economical implementation. It does some unnecessary nearest updates and pruning comparisons for simplicity. But its asymptotic performance is as expected for kd-tree NN. After you get this one working, you can use it as a base implementation to squeeze out the extra comparisons.